# How to use correct filter in for loop using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop, filter

I have this Array `["Let me introduce", "Our Values"]`

I use this code:

```
 var dataname: string[] = item[4].namecategory;
         for (var i = 0; i < dataname.length; i++) {
         console.log(dataname[i]); // output dataname[i] Let me introduce dataname[i] Our Values
         }
    this.CrewChannelContents_category = this.CrewChannelContents.filter(x => x.Category.toLowerCase().includes(dataname[i].toLowerCase()));
```

show error

> ```
> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
> ```

data from this.CrewChannelContents

```
[
                    {
                        Id: "15",
                        Category: "Our Values,WIDE",
                        Date: new Date('2019-12-02'),
                        
                    },
                    {
                        Id: "17",
                        Category: "Let me introduce",
                        Date: new Date('2019-12-05'),
                    
                    },.....
]
```

Updated code:

```
 let tmpVal;
                    for (var i = 0; i < dataname.length; i++) {
                        tmpVal = this.CrewChannelContents.filter(x => x.Category.toLowerCase().includes(dataname[i].toLowerCase()));
                        if (tmpVal) this.CrewChannelContents_category.push(tmpVal)
                        console.log(this.CrewChannelContents_category)
                    }
```

error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'push' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of
> undefined

in filter line.

Please can you share with me any idea, how to filter when I have data an array?

Thank you all

UPDATED CODE (2)

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataname.length; i++) {
                    console.log(this.CrewChannelContents.filter(x => x.Category.toLowerCase().includes(dataname[i].toLowerCase())));
                    this.CrewChannelContents_category = this.CrewChannelContents.filter(x => x.Category.toLowerCase().includes(dataname[i].toLowerCase()));
                    this.tmpvalue.push(this.CrewChannelContents_category);
                    console.log(this.tmpvalue)
                }
```

get an Array like [image]

Comment: Can you supply sample data for `this.CrewChannelContents`?

Comment: I get data from `this.CrewChannelContents` like in update post. Thanks

Comment: move this line into your loop this.CrewChannelContents_category = this.CrewChannelContents.filter(x => x.Category.toLowerCase().includes(dataname[i].toLowerCase()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to include your filter check inside your loop:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
   CrewChannelContents_category: string[];

   ngOnInit() {

        var data = [{
            Id: "15",
            Category: "Our Values,WIDE",
            Date: new Date('2019-12-02'),
        },
        {
            Id: "17",
            Category: "Let me introduce",
            Date: new Date('2019-12-05'),
        }]
    
    
    
        var dataname = ["Let me introduce", "Our Values"];
    
        // reset the CrewChannelContents_category variable
        this.CrewChannelContents_category = [];
        let tmpVal
        for (var i = 0; i < dataname.length; i++) {
            tmpVal = data.filter(x => x.Category.toLowerCase().includes(dataname[i].toLowerCase()));
            if (tmpVal) this.CrewChannelContents_category.push(tmpVal)
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Yes it's correct. But now I have another problems. I have `*ngFor="let item of CrewChannelContents_category "` and show only data for `Our Values` category, because are different array

Comment: tmpVal show only data for `"Let me introduce"` category and  `core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: `uncaught in promise` - I don't see any promise statement above, can you update with all relevant code?

Comment: I'm confused. The code sample does produce an array of objects which would iterate over an *ngFor loop. Your most recent error means that your code is not seeing `this.CrewChannelContents_category` as an available variable. Are you initializing it at the top of your page? - I will update my answer to show where that variable gets initialized

Comment: I updated my code again. I want to know if it's important to get an one array with all data, not 2 array or more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231676/discussion-between-john-tyner-and-site).

Answer (score 0):

It is because you use dataname[i] outside loop where i is greater than dataname length.
So, for filtering you can use:

```
var data = [
  {
    Id: "15",
    Category: "Our Values,WIDE",
    Date: new Date("2019-12-02")
  },
  {
    Id: "17",
    Category: "Let me introduce",
    Date: new Date("2019-12-05")
  }
];
var dataname = ["Let me introduce", "Our Values"];
console.log(
  data.filter((x) =>
    dataname.some((y) => x.Category.toLowerCase().includes(y.toLowerCase()))
  )
);
```

Reference to how array.some() works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some